# How do I stack images on top of each other wrapped in the same div, and then have them separate with animation when I hover?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="mySlides">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
    <img src="4.jpg"/>
    <img src="5.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mySlides {
    padding-top: 25%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}
.mySlides img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 35%;
}


.mySlides img:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

This will be repeated for all images, i.e. nth-of-type(2,3,4,5)

```
.mySlides img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #eaeaea);
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

I wanted to stack the images on top of each other and have them all centered on the screen.
On hovering I wanted the images to separate horizontally while still maintaining the animation.

Comment: Do u have any inspiration link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

Working fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/RaajNadar/L0ennqwp/

Html

```
<div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.mySlides {
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  transition: left 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

.mySlides:hover img:last-child {
  left: 300px;
}
```

Also got a nice animation.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
.mySlides {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mySlides:hover img {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/000000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/003300" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/00ff00" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/006600" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/ff0000" />
</div>
```